# jQueryUI Resizable ignores containment offset (left, top) if container is sibling to resizable

Tags: jquery-ui-resizable

I have 3 layers of divs:

1. background for iframe area (not the whole iframe) (z-index: 0;) (containment for Resizable)
2. iframe (z-index: 1;)
3. selection above iframe (z-index: 2;) (Resizable)

I need use the background as containment for selection. Due to z-index issues I can not use the background as parent for Resizable. So they are siblings. But Resizable seems to ignore 'left' and 'top' of its container in this case.
The minimal example to show the problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        html, body, div {
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;
            top: 20px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        #resizable {
            position: absolute;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#resizable").resizable({
                handles: 'n, e, w, s',
                containment: "#container"
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="resizable"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Such way has glitches, especially in Firefox:**

```
resize: function(event, ui){
    var pos = $('#container').position(); // May not work. var left = $('#container')[0].offsetLeft works better.
    if (ui.position.left < pos.left) {
        ui.position.left = ui.originalPosition.left;
        ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width; // Without this width will grow when handle outside container.
    }
    if (ui.position.top < pos.top)  {
        ui.position.top = ui.originalPosition.top;
        ui.size.height = ui.originalSize.height; // Without this height will grow when handle outside container.
    }
}
```

And for now I disabled 'w' and 'n' handles of my Resizable.

**So what another workarounds there exist?**

BTW, Draggable has no such issue.